# Are multiple ActiveRecord instances kept in sync automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assume this code

```
instance1 = MyModel.find(1)
instance2 = MyModel.find(1)
```

Is `instance1.equals(instance2)` true? (i.e. are they the same objects?)

And after this:

```
instance1.my_column = "new value"
```

Does `instance2.my_column` also contain "new value"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You can keep `instance2` in sync with `reload`.

```
instance1 = MyModel.find(1)
instance2 = MyModel.find(1)

instance1.my_column = "new value"
instance2.my_column 
# => old value

instance1.save!
instance2.my_column 
# => old value

instance2.reload
instance2.my_column 
# => new value
```

Keep in mind you must save `instance1` changes to the database.

Answer (score 3):

weppos is completely correct for the second part of your question. For the first part then there are some subtle difference to equality dependent on how you are testing.

```
instance1.eql?(instance2)
  => true
```

.eql? checks if the objects have the same type and value whereas

```
instance1.equal?(instance2)
  => false
```

.equal? checks if the objects have the same object_id and returns false because

```
instance1.object_id
  => 18277960
instance2.object_id
  => 18271750
```

There is a good article on this subject [here](http://kentreis.wordpress.com/2007/02/08/identity-and-equality-in-ruby-and-smalltalk/)

Answer (score 2):

1. instance1.equals(instance2) is not true. In Rails they are not the same objects. AFAIK, In Merb they would
2. instance2.my_column won't contain a new value, unless you save instance1 and do instance2.reload

Answer (score 0):

@Steve Weet

```
instance1 = User.find(1)
instance2 = User.find(1)
instance1 == instance2   # -> true
instance1.name = "zhangsan"
instance1 == instance2   # true  (not false)
instance1.id = 0
instance1 == instance2   # false (this time)
instance1.id = 1
instance1 == instance2   # true  (oh..)
```

so...this indicate that `rails` check the model `equality` depends on its `id` attribute.
BTW: I test is in ruby193/rails4rc